# Scala: Idiomatic way to convert Map[String, String] to String

Tags: scala

I have a map that contains a few `HTTP` parameters that will be sent to an API.

```
val sortedParameters: SortedMap[String, String] = SortedMap(
        "oauth_nonce" -> nonce,
        "oauth_callback" -> callbackURL,
        "oauth_signature_method" -> signatureMethod,
        "oauth_consumer_key" -> consumerKey
      )
```

The above parameters have to be URL encoded and concatenated in the form `key1=value1&key2=value2` etc. 
What would be the best idiomatic way to achieve this in Scala?

Comment: Whatever library you use to send the request, already has a way to set and encode the parameters. Don't reinvent the bicycle.

Comment: Don't convert to String unless for debug. See the other comment.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much the same as the other answer but including encoding.

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

scala> val enc = (s: String) => java.net.URLEncoder.encode(s, "utf-8")
enc: String => String = $$Lambda$1060/160696258@6c796cc1

scala> val sortedMap = SortedMap("a" -> "b&&c means both b and c are true", "c" -> "d=1")
sortedMap: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[String,String] = Map(a -> b&&c means both b and c are true, c -> d=1)

scala> sortedMap.map(kv => s"${enc(kv._1)}=${enc(kv._2)}").mkString("&")
res2: String = a=b%26%26c+means+both+b+and+c+are+true&c=d%3D1
```

EDIT:
And a more idiomatic destructuring from a comment:

```
sortedMap.map({ case (k, v) => s"${enc(k)}=${enc(v)}" }).mkString("&")
res2: String = a=b%26%26c+means+both+b+and+c+are+true&c=d%3D1
```

Comment: for idiom, `m.map { case (k, v) => s"${enc(k)}=${env(v)}" }`.

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` on each elem to create `k=v` pattern then concat them using `TraversableOnce#foldLeft(z)(op)` or `TraversableOnce#mkString(separator)`

example,

```
scala> import scala.collection.SortedMap
import scala.collection.SortedMap

scala> val sortedParameters = SortedMap("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
sortedParameters: scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

using `mkString`,

```
scala> sortedParameters.map(kv => kv._1 + "=" + kv._2).mkString("&")
res1: String = a=1&b=2&c=3
```

using `foldLeft`,

```
scala> sortedParameters.map(kv => kv._1 + "=" + kv._2)
                       .foldLeft(new String)((a, b) => { if(a.equals("")) b else a + "&" + b})
res2: String = a=1&b=2&c=3
```